# How to filter a list and/or update variable's value using Picker (segmented control)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, list, swiftui

**How to properly filter a list and/or update variable's value using Picker (segmented control) in SwiftUI?**

EXAMPLE:

So far I am using buttons in ContentView to filter a list with data from CoreData. Current buttons and TransactionsListView call:

```
Button("Show income") {
    self.incomeTypeFilter = true
}

Button("Show expenses") {
    self.incomeTypeFilter = false
}

Button("Show ALL") {
    self.incomeTypeFilter = nil
}

TransactionsListView(filter: incomeTypeFilter)
```

And in TransactionsListView I am using this code to filter a list of items:

```
init(filter: Bool?) {
    if let filter = filter {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Transaction>(entity: Transaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "income = %d", filter))
    } else {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Transaction>(entity: Transaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    }
}
```

How to use a Picker (Segmented Control) instead of buttons?
I have a Picker like this:

```
Picker(selection: $transactionType, label: Text("Picker")) {
    Text("All").tag(0)
    Text("Income").tag(1)
    Text("Expenses").tag(2)
}
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

But I don't know how to update self.incomeTypeFilter value based on Picker selection. Or maybe I should have a `TransactionsListView(filter: incomeTypeFilter)` call in a loop where I will pass different values based on selected segment in Picker? What is the proper way of filtering a list and/or updating var's value using Picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo how this could be done (instead of 0,1,2 it can be used enum as better design, but this does not change the idea):

```
struct TestPickerWithBinding: View {
    @State var incomeTypeFilter: Bool? = nil
    var transactionType: Binding<Int> { Binding<Int>(
        get: {
            if let flag = self.incomeTypeFilter {
                return flag ? 1 : 2
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        },
        set: {
            switch $0 {
            case 1:
                self.incomeTypeFilter = true
            case 2:
                self.incomeTypeFilter = false
            default:
                self.incomeTypeFilter = nil
            }
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: transactionType, label: Text("Picker")) {
                Text("All").tag(0)
                Text("Income").tag(1)
                Text("Expenses").tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Divider()
            Text("Filter: \(nil == incomeTypeFilter ? "All" : (incomeTypeFilter! ? "Income" : "Expences"))")
        }

    }
}

struct TestPickerWithBinding_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestPickerWithBinding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Asperi. In general, it works. But when I used your code in my app, 2nd option (Income) is selected by default in Segmented Control and I need to make 1st the default one (if I use your code as a standalone example, the 1st one is default). Also, I don't understand what is happening in this get, set and if let flag part. Could you elaborate  or give me a link to some docs or at least a name of this method? I would like to learn it. I understand just this switch with cases part.

Comment: I found out why the 2nd segment was selected. My mistake, I didn't change `@State var incomeTypeFilter: Bool? = true` to be `@State var incomeTypeFilter: Bool? = nil`. Now it works as expected. Asperi, I would appreciate if you could explain more about why did you use get and set and this If condition in get. Or at least point me to some documentation about this part.

Comment: The `Binding(get:set:)` is a special constructor to create calculable binding to _anything_ so it needs `get` part closure to get value and `set` part closure to set value (in your case from Picker to optional Bool variable. `if let` is a swift statement for explicitly unwrap Optional with assignment to provided variable (in this case `flag`), it is actually shorter of `if optional != nil { let a= optional!; _use_a_here_} else { _do_anything_else}`